# Delphi - Hook WIN key on keyboard for show my start menu

Tags: delphi

I use `SetWindowsHookEx()` with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`.

I want to hook the <kbd>WIN</kbd> keys to open my application, but the problem is if I press <kbd>WIN+R</kbd>, etc, then this key shortcut does not work.

My source is inspired by this code:

https://github.com/MasterOfChaos/Chaoslauncher/blob/master/Source/Plugins/Chaosplugin/Hotkeys.pas

Please help me.  How can I open my application with the <kbd>WIN</kbd> keys on the keyboard, and still work with <kbd>WIN+R</kbd>, <kbd>WIN+E</kbd>, <kbd>WIN+L</kbd>, etc?

Comment: The WIN keys are reserved for Windows' use. Why do you want to remap them? Users are not going to expect that behavior. At the very least, consider using a hotkey via [`RegisterHotKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) instead. And many modern keyboards have user-defined shortcut keys available, you should use those when available (see [`WM_APPCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275.aspx)). I suggest you run a background process with a hidden `HWND` to handle these kind of events, instead of using a keyboard hook.

Comment: Doesn't work because you're (most probably) eating that WIN key. You could do what you want with key up event.

Comment: The Windows key is only for use by Windows. That's why it's called the Windows key. Users are going to hate your app, because they expect the Windows key to do specific things that are part of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This work me fine:

```
const
WH_KEYBOARD_LL   =   13;
LLKHF_ALTDOWN    =   $00000020;
LLKHF_INJECTED   =   $00000010;
KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0;

type
tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   record
    vkCode:   DWORD;
    scanCode:   DWORD;
    flags:   DWORD;
    time:   DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo:   DWORD;
  end;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   ^KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   ^KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;

var
hhkLowLevelKybd:   HHOOK;
prev:PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
KeysPressed: tstringlist;



function LowLevelKeyBoardProc(nCode:   Integer;   awParam:   WPARAM;   
alParam:   LPARAM):   LRESULT;   stdcall;
var
fEatKeyStroke:   Boolean;
act:   PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;

begin
fEatKeystroke   :=   False;


if (nCode = HC_ACTION) then
begin
    case awParam  of
        WM_KEYDOWN,
        WM_SYSKEYDOWN,
        WM_KEYUP,
        WM_SYSKEYUP:
            begin
            act   :=   PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(alParam);

            // start sezereme jen pokud je zmacnute jen jedno tlacitko a je to Win
            if KeysPressed.Count=1 then begin if act^.vkCode = VK_LWIN then fEatKeystroke := True; end;

            // pokud zmacnke tlacitko pridame do listboxu, v kombinaci at tam jsou dva stisky
            if awParam=WM_KEYDOWN then
               if KeysPressed.IndexOf(char(act^.vkCode))=-1 then KeysPressed.Add(char(act^.vkCode)); // prida do listboxu

            // pokud uz neni zmacknute smazeme
            if awParam=WM_KEYUP then
               KeysPressed.Clear;


            end; // case
            end;//case
end;//nCode




if fEatKeyStroke then
   Result := 1
else
   Result := CallNextHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd, nCode, awParam, alParam);




end;





procedure InstallHook;
begin
KeysPressed := tstringlist.Create;
if hhkLowLevelKybd <> 0 then exit;
hhkLowLevelKybd := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @LowLevelKeyboardProc,   
hInstance,   0);
end;

procedure UninstallHook;
begin
KeysPressed.Free;
if hhkLowLevelKybd = 0 then exit;
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd);
hhkLowLevelKybd := 0;
end;




procedure TFrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
InstallHook;
end;



procedure TFrmMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
UninstallHook;
end;
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I copied, pasted, rotated and it worked! Congratulations on finding the answer and including such a complete example. All that's left now is for you to come back here and accept your own answer as the correct one!